# Calculation of directory size in DOS batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have written a Batch file to get the disk space from the list of directories provided. While converting the bytes to KB or MB, no data getting printed.

```
@echo OFF
REM SQL CALL TO GET THE DIRECTORY LISTING
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (directoryList.txt) DO (
    for /F "tokens=3" %%S in ('dir %%i ^| findstr /c:"File(s)"') do (
        SETLOCAL
        SET /A "sizeKB=%%S/1024"
        SET /A "sizeMB=%sizeKB% / 1024"
        ECHO "Directory :: %%i with size :: %%S "
        ECHO "IN MEGABYTE :: %sizeMB%"
        ENDLOCAL
        PAUSE
    )
)
```

Output of the above script is ...

```
Directory :: D:\xxx with size :: 723,234,123
IN MEGABYTE ::
```

Please correct the above code.

Comment: if your folder size exceeds 2GB, all calculations will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo OFF
REM SQL CALL TO GET THE DIRECTORY LISTING
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (directoryList.txt) DO (
    for /F "tokens=3" %%S in ('dir /-c "%%i" ^| findstr /c:"File(s)"') do (
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        SET /A "sizeKB=%%S/1024"
        SET /A "sizeMB=!sizeKB! / 1024"
        ECHO "Directory :: %%i with size :: %%S "
        ECHO "IN KBYTE :: !sizeKB!"
        ECHO "IN MEGABYTE :: !sizeMB!"
        ENDLOCAL
        PAUSE
    )
)
```

Comment: please remember, `"File(s)"` depends on local settings. in French `fichier(s)`, in Polish `plik(ów)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting text `723,234,123`, which is not converted to a number because of `,`

Remove then, before aritmetic:

```
SET "sizeB=%%c"
SET "sizeB=!sizeB:,=!"
SET /A "sizeKB=!sizeB!/1024"
...
```

Comment: In RGuggisberg's code he doesn't get `,` commas.

Comment: As you wisely noted, `"File(s)"` depends on local settings. Number format also (in my system, dots are used). And you can see commas in output received in question text.

Comment: I mean the answer, not the question. Please look at `dir /?`  on the command line.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh!!! Ok, right! Didn't know `/-c` switch. Neither @RGuggisberg pointed that on answer.